# Encryption and file format in Kleopatra. Can't encrypt using Public Key

Tags: encryption, pgp, openpgp

I created PGP key pair and I exported private and public key files. I know that files are fine because I was able to encrypt/decrypt files in GpgFrontend app using these keys. I was also able to do the same using Bouncy Castle library in C#.

**Two questions:**

1: In Kleopatra, I can't encrypt file with Public Key only. For some reason it doesn't work. Option is not available. To be able to encrypt/decrypt I have to load Private key. What is it that I am missing?

2: I am confused with encrypted data. When I open encrypted PGP file, data looks something like this:

…F†u—PEÛ Ù×´‡Ó"gÆx=ÑoãÝSŒ6M)!ÑÙ×g|;ä    @+Pa,²TDV„ëùqá²*”—}×±dCÐÊsf^:Š†7¶LØnš{‹‰ždºV°G­(¸7Rd ôUµD@9ÖÕ÷ü Ý dëE¶-ýû¾/khØÇ~Zˆ0:±ðU5É¥žÇé¯7M Ôà}Ò:ÕÈàÒ€snœ­‘èÁq§ÀJ®zU’èDc%ß˜–yí|ê±«M„ð™=Üæ0ß| 5|¾ªô Åíú_lªkó‰Ùª>/–þ€ÈðkvÖwãz9Y±ŠÜW½ìFÍþ{ãF­ÔS   fýâÚÐpá
8Z_.eÄŽÂU)õœ-•êSQÁ\¼—? ¥ã¢O¯J•ÔÖ    D;<kÔPÚ.8ÀKƒNÒ€3túø°ÒºA¼ ‡KèÁ›X

but, when I use Notepad option in Kleopatra (or in GpgFrontend), and when I encrypt some text, encrypted data looks like this:

-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
hF4D1F0XuQWmdMYSAQdAJaVSF+2pME685EMW2M/xDKPKE6BxJiSYSgP06GGKUVgw
P+7Y91/iMOHz2dB4K2clkjgLbWXvy+DRlkBKXGzs7lSK6c3+HFv1L+EIj+mm+dni
1MAGAQkCEP6UbLZfq+aFWK3Fs4H7j05XYdovJvZv9GKEBQCbGT4PjB1ZrxkC+VfO
ybB5R6cWJMdo1mdUg05KAAfSinOM/19gXBrh2pwO/snX/bK7M1iA+qi0rYcGl7Lu
ijHm6PA1c8LBMKFz7Xc6lcA5CtsLTseHHHGEtQCt6Hd/z0EvQUA0FdiYKcieX/lA
W8y0V+Xjao86VmRNYVryx6pRmbq5+vN7H/9hnDNUxgzxVb/yQ90FePzDK73V/bsT
Im2MNTma9ruB
=j0ZY
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----

Why does encrypted data look different?

Thank you

Comment: One is "ascii armored" (essentially base 64 encoded), the other is not. Kleopatra issues are off-topic on stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why are Kleopatra issues off-topic?

Comment: Stackoverflow is only for programming problems, not general software issues.